# CoreData: One-To-Many Relationship Display Issue

Tags: uitableview, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I realise this is quite lengthy but I'm currently working on my first CoreData project and despite reading every resource i can find its just not all sinking in yet. so far i have got it saving and persisting all okay however i can't seem to get the relationship to work correctly. 
I have a table view that displays Exersize Categorys which moves to a table displaying its associated Exersizes (one-to-many).

(tried to post an image but i don't have enough rep points yet) but the dataModel looks like this

ExersizeCategory<--->>Exersize

From everything that I've read i believe that i may need to use a predicate to filter the results, but I'm confused as to how this actually works and weather or not I'm actually even creating and saving the Exersize Categorys and Exersizes objects appropriately for the relationship to work in the first place.

Here's how I'm creating and saving (also setting its name to the textfield entry)

```
ExersizeCategory *exersizeCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExersizeCategory"
                                                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    exersizeCategory.name = self.textField.text;

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database
```

And here is the code for the exersizes (pretty much identical)

```
// Create a new instance of the entity 
    exersize = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exersize"
                                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    exersize.name = self.textField.text;

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];  // write to database
```

Although this seems to work in creating the objects and I'm seeing them on the tableviews i have yet to implement the coreDataGeneratedAccessors, how and where do those fit into the picture?

```
@interface ExersizeCategory (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
```

- (void)addExersizesObject:(Exersize *)value;
- (void)removeExersizesObject:(Exersize *)value;
- (void)addExersizes:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeExersizes:(NSSet *)values;

i should mention that I'm using the CoreDataTableViewController class which seems to reduce the amount of code you need to write to fetch(which i found through a tutorial i was going through at www.timroadly.com) created by stanford university. side-note:Would it be better to not subclass this and just use the standard way as i noticed in the .h it states its copyrighted to Stanford so I'm unsure as to if i can use it in an app i want to release?

Here's how I'm currently fetching to display the Exersizes

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController {
// 1 - Decide what Entity you want
NSString *entityName = @"Exersize"; // Put your entity name here
NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

// 2 - Request that Entity
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

// 3 - Filter it if you want

//currently unsure about this!
//request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@""];

// 4 - Sort it if you want
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
// 5 - Fetch it
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
[self performFetch];
```

}

I know I've missed key pieces in implementing this but I'm just not sure which and where.
Ive only been at core data for a few days so its been pretty hefty to learn!

Thank you to anyone that can shed light/answer/ or even push me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

f.perdition,

You write:

> Although this seems to work in creating the objects and I'm seeing
>   them on the tableviews i have yet to implement the
>   coreDataGeneratedAccessors, how and where do those fit into the
>   picture?

Core Data dynamically creates the implementations of those methods. The headers are for your convenience and complier type checking.

Here is a simple predicate to find an exercise name on your `exersize` entity:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K == %@", @"name", @"Push Up"];
```

Andrew

P.S. You may want to correct your spelling of the word exercise.

Comment: hello andrew good shout on the spelling, however ill keep it the same just for the moment for the sake of consistency. after trying a few more things and a bit more reading, i believe i have it fetching correctly however when I'm creating the exersize object i can't seem to place it in the relationship as the NSSet count for exersizes remains at 0. I've tried [exersizeCategory addExersizesObject:exersize]; but that doesn't seem to work? I've tried all the solutions i could find but I'm still going wrong somewhere, does anything seem obviously wrong to you? thanks again

Comment: f.perdition, Every CD relationship has an inverse. Hence, if the relation is a one-to-many and the inverse is one-to-one, then the relationship can be built by a simple assignment. As in: `exercise.exercises = exercises;`. Andrew

Comment: Andrew, i can't seem to get that to work, same issue as before. The exerciseCategory objects are being created fetched and displayed as they should however the exercises themselves arnt. through print statements i can see that the managed object context is being passed on and something is being created however the NSSet remain empty and so does the tableview I'm guessing that because its fetching associated entries and as nothings been added to it its got nothing to fetch. any ideas what might be going on? i could update my post to show more code if it'll help the situation? cheers man!

Comment: Hi, did you ever found absolution, I have the exactly same question/problem?.... Thank you very much for your response in advance.